# How to know what record(s) was updated, deleted, or inserted in wpf with linq to sql concept

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql

```
 MydatabaseDataContext MyDB = new MydatabaseDataContext();

 Employee MyEmp = new Employee();
 MyEmp.EmpID = 5039;
 MyEmp.EmpName = "XXX";
 MyDB.Employees.InsertOnSubmit(MyEmp);
 MyDB.SubmitChanges();

 IQueryable<Employee> _DeleteQuery = from dq in MyDB.Employees where dq.EmpID == 5039 select dq;
 foreach (Employee delete in _DeleteQuery)
 {
      MyDB.Employees.DeleteOnSubmit(delete);
 }
 MyDB.SubmitChanges();

 IQueryable<Employee> _UpdateQuery = from uq in MyDB.Employees where uq.EmpID == 5039 select uq;

 foreach (Employee Update in _UpdateQuery)
 {
     Update.EmpName = "yyy";
 }
 MyDB.SubmitChanges();
```

With  above code i can insert, delete and update record.If the  insert, delete and update is finished in successful , i have to display some message like "Insert, delete and update is finished in successfullY".

In ADO.NET It will return some int value(1). But i dont know how get the value like that in  linq to sql concept.

If i get that value,i can display some message which is mentioned above. So what should i do for that

Comment: In what sense do you think records will not be inserted, deleted, or updated after a call to `SubmitChanges`?  It will delete if it can -- or it will throw an exception if relationships are violated.  It will insert if it can, unless non-null columns are not part of the insertion.  It will update if it can, unless there is nothing to update.  Is it just the latter you are asking about?  Are you only curious about what was *modified*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [DataContext.GetChangeSet Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx). `ChangeSet.ToString()` will give you a message like

> {Inserts: x, Deletes: x, Updates: x}

You can access the [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.changeset_properties) directly too

```
int itemsToAddBeforeSubmitChanges = MyDB.GetChangeSet().Inserts.Count;
MyDB.SubmitChanges();
int itemsToAddAfterSubmitChanges = MyDB.GetChangeSet().Inserts.Count;
```

Comment: Thank you so much LPL.You explained me what i need exactly.